# springboot java interceptor doesn't invoke TRACE commad

Tags: java, spring-boot, interceptor

I define an interceptor in spring-boot.
I override the `preHandle` method.
the interceptor is invoking for all HTTP commands : GET/PUT/POST/PATCH/DELETE/HEAD/OPTIONS
but it doesn't invoked for TRACE command.

what am I miss?

the interceptor:

```
@Component
public class BlockingHttpInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {

    private final Class<?> thisClass = this.getClass();

    private String BASE_URL = "/subscribers";

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if (HttpMethod.GET.matches(request.getMethod())
                || HttpMethod.POST.matches(request.getMethod())
                || (HttpMethod.DELETE.matches(request.getMethod()) && request.getRequestURI().startsWith(BASE_URL))
                || HttpMethod.PATCH.matches(request.getMethod())) {
            return true;
        } else {
            response.sendError(HttpStatus.METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED.value());
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

the interceptor config:

```
@Configuration
public class InterceptorConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Autowired
    private BlockingHttpInterceptor blockingHttpInterceptor;

    @Override
    public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry){
        registry.addInterceptor(blockingHttpInterceptor).addPathPatterns("/**");
    }
}
```

Comment: java : 8
spring-boot version: 2.5.6
springframework-security: 5.5.3

Comment: The `DispatcherServlet` by default doesn't dispatch TRACE request. Add `spring.mvc.dispatch-trace-request=true` to your properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in the [JavaDoc for the `DispatcherServlet`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/FrameworkServlet.html#setDispatchTraceRequest(boolean)) the TRACE request are by default not dispatched, hence they will never reach your controllers/interceptor.

Luckily you are using Spring Boot which makes configuring this quite easy through the `spring.mvc.dispatch-trace-request` property, which is by default `false`. Setting this to `true` in your `application.properties` will enable dispatching for TRACE request.

```
spring.mvc.dispatch-trace-request=true
```

Adding the above to your properties will enable it and will make things work as you expect.